# Can't get video meta from wp_read_video_metadata()

Tags: custom-field, videos

This is what I'm doing:

```
$video_url = get_field('video_file', $post->ID);
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$uploads_dir = ( $uploads['basedir'] . $uploads['subdir'] );
$file = $uploads_dir .'/'. basename($video_url);
$metadata = wp_read_video_metadata( $file );
```

The `$video_url` is giving me a URL to video file: http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/video.mp4

When I `var_dump()` the `$metadata` I'm getting `bool(false)`.
The video file exists, it's accessible through URL. I need to get video meta, please help.

EDIT: I have require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' ); on my custom page and I'm using ACF to get video URL.

Comment: `wp_read_video_metadata()` returns the array of metadata, if found, or `false` if otherwise. In your case, if your file exists, it has no ID3 meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure you're getting the correct path to the video, pass the ID to `get_attached_file()`, and use that in `wp_read_video_metadata()`. `wp_upload_dir()` is for getting/creating a directory to write to *now*, so if the file has not been uploaded in the current month, the path will not be correct if you just add it to the filename.

```
$attachment_id = get_field( 'video_file', $post->ID, false); // Get the raw value, the attachment ID.
$file = get_attached_file( $attachment_id );
$metadata = wp_read_video_metadata( $file );
```